# Extracting years from data

Tags: python, time

I want to extract data for years in the table below. Data are in the format `datetime64` and this data you can see below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
         'Date': ['2021-01-01','2020-01-01','2019-01-01','2028-01-01']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date'
                                   ])
df['Date']= df['Date'].astype('datetime64')

df
```

Now I want to subtract this data from 2023-01-01 in order to calculate how many years have been between this date and the data in the table . To do this I tried with the row below but unfortunately this did not work

```
df['Date']-['2023-01-01'].astype('datetime64')
```

So can anybody help me with how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the reference to [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
df['days'] = df['Date'] - pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01')

# or
df['days'] = df['Date'].sub(pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01'))
```

Output:

```
        Date       days
0 2021-01-01  -730 days
1 2020-01-01 -1096 days
2 2019-01-01 -1461 days
3 2028-01-01  1826 days
```

For the reversed operation:

```
df['days'] = pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01') - df['Date']

# or
df['days'] = df['Date'].rsub(pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01'))
```

Output:

```
        Date       days
0 2021-01-01   730 days
1 2020-01-01  1096 days
2 2019-01-01  1461 days
3 2028-01-01 -1826 days
```

*Note that a preferred method to convert the Dates is [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).*

For years, you can further divide by `np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')`:

```
df['years'] = df['Date'].sub(pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01')).div(np.timedelta64(1, 'Y'))
```

Output:

```
        Date     years
0 2021-01-01 -1.998672
1 2020-01-01 -3.000746
2 2019-01-01 -4.000082
3 2028-01-01  4.999418
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert your dates in `datetime` format and the apply the subtraction for the column `Date`:

```
def years_to_2023(date):
  diff = datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0,0,0) - datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
  return int(diff.days/365)

df['Date'].apply(lambda date: years_to_2023(date))
```

Remember to:

```
import datetime
```

The output should be:

```
0    2  #2021
1    3  #2020
2    4  #2019
3   -5  #2028
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```